# SQL Alter database failed - being used by checkpoint process

Tags: sql-server-2008, blocking

On my SQL server 2008, i have a SQL agent job to restore a database on nightly basis. Procedure:

1. find latest backup on other server
2. Kill all conenction to the destination database
3. Restore destination database with replace, recovery

It failed last weekend because the database was being used by a system process (spid 11 checkpoint). since I couldnt kill the system process, I fixed this by restarting sql server.
It failed this weekend as well with same error (checkpint process in this database as from `sp_who`) and when I run:

```
SELECT session_id,request_id,command,status,start_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests 
WHERE session_id = 11
```

It shows:

```
11  0   CHECKPOINT  background  2010-04-06 10:17:49.103
```

I cant restart the server every time it fails.
Can anyone please help me in fixing this?

Thanks in advance

Manjot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed-
since it was restored daily. i have excluded it from re-index, dbcc checkdb, update stats etc maintenance plans.

even though they ran during seperate schedule, excluding the database fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Don't kill SPIDs less than 50! These are system processes

To see if you can take the DB out of the "restoring" state try

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDB WITH RECOVERY
```

Edit, after comment

Assuming you want to restore the DB and don't care about keeping it...

Stop SQL Server, move the MDF/LDF somewhere else, start SQL Server.

The DB comes up offline (I forget the exact status). Then you can drop it, restore it

Comment: Tried this. since the no log file was restored on top, I doesn't let me do this. :-(

Comment: yes i am sure that it will be fixed after restart.
It got it fixed last time when i restarted. But i cant restart the server everytime for this. Is there no way that i can fix it without a restart?

Comment: @manjot: It sounds like your restore process is broken somehow. I assumed it was a one off you wanted to fix. You could DROp before restore everytime though

Comment: If there is a system process,which you cant kill. You cant even drop the database because drop doesnt work if there is an open connection. Isnt it?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. I have tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than killing the open connections, try

```
ALTER DATABASE myDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Then do the restore, or better yet, drop it, then restore.

After you're done, don't forget to return the database to its previous state:

```
ALTER DATABASE myDatabase SET MULTI_USER
```

Comment: As my database is in restoring state it says "ALTER DATABASE is not permitted while a database is in the Restoring state"
Can't drop it as it is in use by this SPID.